# Is there a word for the transfer of contact information (say giving a business card)

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a single word or phrase that can be used to describe:

- The transfer of contact data (ex: name, phone number, address, etc)
- (Optional) The connecting with somebody (in my sense on social media)

Most importantly i'm looking for a word or phrase to capture the **act** of giving somebody your say business card.

Comment: _Networking_ is the usual phrase.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have edited the question to narrow the scope a bit

Comment: There's no word for that particular act. English has a million or so words, but there are far, far more human events we might want to describe. It's an aspect of (a step in the dance of) networking, which is an ongoing process.

Comment: I feel sure the Japanese have a word for it, though, for the life of me, I cannot think what it is. They do it, as is their wont, in a very formal ceremony. The two businessmen face one another and bow, and whilst bowing, each protrudes an arm with their business card, and each takes the other's card.

Comment: You can call this _self-promotion_ also.

Comment: I can think of two ways someone might describe this: 1) "I gave him my card" and 2) "We exchanged [business] cards".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said **networking** is a general term that encompasses the exchange of contact details, but also includes chatting, schmoozing, finding common ground etc.

More specific phrases you would use are **exchanging contact details** or **giving contact details**.

Eg.

> I met a guy in the defense industry at a bar last night. We *exchanged contact details* and he said he'd give me a call about a job opening later in the week.

Or.

> The young fellow I met seemed especially keen. I *gave him my contact details* and told him to call me if he wanted a job.